# How to run multiple stores in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart

Is it possible to have multiple stores with different admin and roles in OpenCart?

Comment: As far as i've ever been able to make out, admin users are applicable to all stores.

Comment: You should accept an answer - there is nothing else to think of or that could be done and it is the best answer to date. You can accept the answer by clicking on the **tick** underneath the answer's up/down vote buttons...

Answer (score 2):

You can set various permissions during the insert of a new group or user, however because you are administering all the sites from one admin it is not possible to make the users view only the orders or items etc applicable to one store.

You can get an extension which will do this though: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8336

Hope that helps